# How to block inline javascript in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The need is to replace a website syntax highlighter with another one. I've succeeded in block related JS and CSS file by add this in `manifest.json` file:

```
"background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": [   
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "http://*.oschina.net/", "https://*.oschina.net/"
],
```

and this in `background.js` file:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(){ 
    return {cancel: true}; 
},
{
    urls: [
        "http://my.oschina.net/js/syntax-highlighter-2.1.382/scripts/brush.js",
        "http://my.oschina.net/js/syntax-highlighter-2.1.382/styles/shCore.css",
        "http://my.oschina.net/js/syntax-highlighter-2.1.382/styles/shThemeDefault.css"
    ],
    types: ["script","stylesheet"]
},
["blocking"]
```

);

so the js and css that former syntax highlighter need is blocked, but there is an initialize function called in inline html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = '/js/syntax-highlighter-2.1.382/scripts/clipboard.swf';
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
```

So I got error message in console, how can I block it too in chrome extension scripts?

Comment: Since the JS in inline, you could probably inject a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to run at `document_end`, and have the content script remove the inline script from the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome does not offer any method that allows you to block specific inline scripts. ([`onbeforescriptexecute` is not supported (yet)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168175)).

You could disable *all* inline scripts using the [`chrome.contentSettings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings) API, or per-page by using the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to add a `Content-Security-Policy` header that does not contain `unsafe-inline`.

Most likely you do not want to block all scripts, but only prevent a code snippet from running. There is no one-fits-all method for this, but in your case, you could redirect one of the blocked scripts to a stub that defines the methods, e.g.

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function() {
        return {redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL("brush.js") };
    },
    {
        urls: [
            "http://my.oschina.net/js/syntax-highlighter-2.1.382/scripts/brush.js"
        ],
        types: ["script"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
```

brush.js

```
if (!window.SyntaxHighlighter) window.SyntaxHighlighter = {};
if (!SyntaxHighlighter.config) SyntaxHighlighter.config = {};
SyntaxHighlighter.all = function() {};
```

Do **not forget** to add your script to [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in the manifest file. And don't forget to reload the Chrome extension when you've modified the manifest file.

Comment: Let't me have a try and give a reply. Thx